# Removing startup words and ending words regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of this format and I want only `the-big-bang-theory` from this string.The problem is in this string some words are of variable length

```
media-tv-quotes-2-the-big-bang-theory-94-toprated-2
       ^                               ^    ^     ^
----------------------------------------------------
```

I try with this code but no luck.

```
$keywords = str_replace("/media-[a-z]-quotes-+/","", "media-tv-quotes-2-the-big-bang-theory-94-toprated-2");
```

Anybody knows how can I achieve this.

Thanks..

Comment: You can not use `str_replace` for regex. use `preg_replace`.

Comment: Is the logic that you want the words from the first number until the second number?

Comment: i tried that also but no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following regex:

```
$keywords = preg_replace("/^media-[a-z]+-quotes-\d+-(.*?)-\d+-.*$/", "$1", "media-tv-quotes-2-the-big-bang-theory-94-toprated-2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch anything between 2 numbers:

```
$s = 'media-tv-quotes-2-the-big-bang-theory-94-toprated-2';
preg_match('~\d+-(.+?)-\d+~', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Problem acuress if your movie title has numbers in it, in that case use:

```
$s = 'media-tv-quotes-2-the-big-bang-theory-94-toprated-2';
preg_match('~^media-\w+-\w+-\d+-(.+?)-\d+-\w+-\d+$~i', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$keywords = preg_replace("/^(.*?)(the-big-bang-theory)(.*)$/i","$2", "media-tv-quotes-2-the-big-bang-theory-94-toprated-2");
```

Capture anything characters before `the-big-bang-theory` and after it.
Then only preserve in the replacement `the-big-bang-theory`.

Comment: You can't use `str_replace` with regular expressions. Try `preg_replace`